# private/qringbuffer_p.h: No such file or directory installing QTserialport

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I started talking about this issue here [extrange behavior of serial port using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501131/extrange-behavior-of-serial-port-using-qt) but as it was not the initial topic I have created a new thread.

I am using QT 4.8 in windows XP. In the process of installing the QTSerial Library ,following the qt wiki steps, when building qtserialport.pro I get the error:

private/qringbuffer_p.h: No such file or directory

same happens with

QtCore/qwineventnotifier.h: No such file or directory.

I see those files are in the directory \qt4support\include. I have tried to add the complete path but then new errors appear... I am new to QT and I don't know how it manages the includes. Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install `libqt5serialport5-dev` with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5-dev
```

Comment: qtbase5-private-dev package should be better

Comment: Sorry for necrobumping this but incase for any users of Arch/arch based, just reinstall the qt5-base package or maybe qt6-base in your case